# WPF use string resources in XAML within element tag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multilingual, resourcestring

I am working on creating WPF application that is multi language ready. So, I put all of "translatable" string into string resources.

I know how to use this resources from XAML, but I am having trouble to use it within the ***open and close tag***.

For example:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="2, 5, 0, 0">
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="www.blabla.com/forgotpassword" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">Click here</Hyperlink>
    to reset your password!
</TextBlock>
```

As you can see `Click here` and `to reset your password!` are within element tag. My question is, how to retrieve `Click here` and `to reset your password!` from the string resources?

Here is my string resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XRManager.Resources"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="Click_Here">Click here</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Click_Here_Part_Reset_Password">to reset your password!</system:String>    

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm looking at this too simple, but would something like this suffice?

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="2, 5, 0, 0">
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="www.blabla.com/forgotpassword" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Click_Here}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Click_Here_Part_Reset_Password}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: You were a minute faster then I was. I had done the same. Just with a Label  `<Label Content="{StaticResource Click_Here}"/>`